# I keep getting the same error message about a type error and an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python

```
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk

import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts

from neuralintents import GenericAssistant


class Assistant:

    def __init__(self):
        self.recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        self.speaker = tts.init()
        self.speaker.setProperty("rate", 150)

        self.assistant = GenericAssistant("intents.json", intent_methods={"file": self.create_file})
        self.assistant.train_model()

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(text="", font=("Arial, 120, bold"))
        self.label.pack()

        threading.Thread(target=self.run_assistant).start()

        self.root.mainlroot()

    def create_file(self):
        with open("somefil.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("HELLO WORLD")

    def run_assistant(self):
        while True:
            try:
                with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
                    self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(mic)

                    text = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                    text = text.lower()

                    if "hey mike" in text:
                        self.label.config(fg="red")
                        audio = self.recognizer.listen(mic)
                        text = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                        text = text.lower()
                        if text == "stop":
                            self.speaker.say("Bye")
                            self.speaker.runAndWait()
                            self.speaker.stop()
                            self.root.destroy()
                            sys.exit()
                        else:
                            if text is not None:
                                response = self.assistant.request(text)
                                if response is not None:
                                    self.speaker.say(response)
                                    self.speaker.runAndWait()
                            self.label.config(fg="black")
            except:
                self.label.config(fg="black")
                continue                    

Assistant()
```

The error message says:

```
TypeError: BasicAssistant.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intent_methods'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

From a look at the code of neuralintents here: https://github.com/NeuralNine/neuralintents/blob/master/neuralintents/assistants.py#L20

There is no `intent_methods` keyword argument in BasicAssistant.

Try using `method_mappings` keyword argument instead.

Side note:
There is a warning saying you should not use `GenericAssistant` class: https://github.com/NeuralNine/neuralintents/blob/master/neuralintents/assistants.py#L160
Consider using `BasicAssistant` class